# How to extract file from tar.gz archive to different directory in bash

Tags: command-line, directory, tar

I have tar.gz archive on external drive and to extract I need to copy to my home directory and then extract. Is there a way to have it in one go, extract to /home/me directory without the need to copy it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below commands:-

`tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz -C /home/me`